# python function definition

Tags: python

I am new in python. Can you explain this code?

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    return n*factorial(n-1)

>>>print factorial(5)
>>>120
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is the part you do not understand?

Comment: how about you invest some time in reading a book on python? http://www.coderholic.com/free-python-programming-books/

Answer (score 4):

```
def factorial(n):            # define a function, receiving a value 'n'
    if n == 0:               # if n is 0, then...
        return 1             #    return the result 1 to the calling code (done!)
    return n*factorial(n-1)  # otherwise return n times the result of calling
                             #  this function (factorial) with the lower value

>>>print factorial(5)

# factorial(5): 5 != 0, so return 5 * factorial(4)
#   factorial(4): 4 != 0 ...
#     ...
#           factorial(0) = 1 returns to factorial(1) call:
#         factorial(1) = 1 * 1 = 1, returns to factorial(2) call:
#       factorial(2) = 2 * 1 = 2
#     factorial(3) = 3 * 2 = 6
#   factorial(4) = 4 * 6 = 24
# factorial(5) = 5 * 24 = 120, return this

>>>120
```

This is called *recursion*, which you can find excellent explanations of online. Remember that this is a procedure to follow, so when you see the factorial(n-1) expression, python is calculating n-1, then starting a fresh call to `factorial` here with this value. The result is that each call makes another call to `factorial` until eventually it reaches 0 and it can start going back up the stack to the outermost call. Imagine trying to work out this yourself, and you'll find you're doing the same kind of thing:

```
(5 * (4 * (3 * (2 * (1 * 1)))))
```

You can't complete the outermost bracket until you know the value of the bracket inside it, etc etc.

Beware though, that the code has a major flaw: if n-1-1-1-1-1 etc will never reach 0 (for example, if n=1.1), then it will never reach the `return 1` line, and never get to the bottom of the rabbit hole. In fact it will probably cause a Stack Overflow error because each call takes up a bit more space on the stack and eventually that runs out.

For even further study, learn about tail call recursion (which this is an example of) and how compilers get around the stack overflow problem when the recursive call is in the return statement (tail).

Comment: Very nice depiction of the call stack that comes from the call.

Comment: @sean: Cheers, anything you'd improve?